# How to handle document request in django?

Tags: django

I have three models, `Application, Students and University` in this, application is connected with both student and university (Students can apply for an university and university can manage these applications). Now i have an scenario in which university will be "Requesting for documents" - by which students will upload documents later. I am just confused how to handle this.

**How it happens** - On application details page there is a button named "Request Document", when university clicks on this - a popup with available documents will be showed, in this they can multiselect the document and submit.
And in students side there will be a space where they need to upload all the required documents

So now, from the above i have few problems:

1. How to store these on database, as required documents can be varied (can these be stored in a single row with arrays or should i store each row for each documents?
2. How to show this on students page?
3. How to validate if the required documents are uploaded?

Comment: Add separate models for `DocumentType` and `Document`. `Document` to have a `FleField` and a foreign key to `Student`. You can create a `Document` object when requested and then update the `FileField` when student uploads a file.